# Estimation of a generalized noncentral chi-square dsitribution

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, signal-processing

According to Mathai A, Provost S: *Quadratic Forms in Random Variables: Theory and Applications*, 1992, the quadratic form of normal variables has a generalized noncentral chi-square distribution (or generalized chi-square distribution in wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_chi-squared_distribution).

That is:

$Y = (U+b)^TΛ(U+b)=\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}λ_j(U_j+b_j)^2$

where $U$ is a standard normal vector with elements $U_j$, $b$ is a vector with elements $b_j$, $λ_j$ denotes elements of the digonal matrix $Λ$.

Now, I have samples of $Y$, and I know they follow the generalized noncentral chi-square distribution.

How can I estimate $λ_j,b_j$, or even $n$ from the samples?

Comment: Could you explain how you observe $Y$ and why you believe it follows such a distribution?  It is unusual not to know $n.$

Comment: Well, such distribution is very common in the real world. If the signal and a Gaussian noise go through the Rice channel, the SNR will have such distribution. In power system analysis, if the voltage has a multinormal distribution, the power also has such distribution.

Comment: That might be so, but it doesn't give us any further information about your situation or how we might be able to help with it.